# Javascript Form Validation 4 Number Option

Tags: javascript, html, validation, forms

I've been searching this website for a tutorial on how to write a script that validates a form for four specific numbers. If the data is entered and does not match any of the four numbers, it should alert a 'Not Valid' message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
var validNumbers = /^(123|777|989|111)$/;
var isFormValid = validNumbers.test(input.value);
if (!isFormValid)
{
    alert("Not Valid");
}
```

Comment: Is 'input' a reserved Javascript function/name?